# Getting outliers back to table; Showing outlier value - Python

Tags: python, pandas

1. How can I get the actual outlier value to the print i.e.let's assume that 90 in col a and col c are outliers. So, I want to print the value 90 in the label message. Shall I use get_values?
2. How can I populate the message instead of an outlier? mask?
3. How can I select only outliers in the result?
   [image]

````
df = [{'date': 'a','value1': 90, 'value2': 4, 'value3':3}, {'date': 'a','value1':10, 'value2': 20, 'value3': 30},
       {'date': 'a','a':60, 'b': 9, 'c': 30}] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

#removing the date col
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols.remove('date')
def outlier_label(x, lower, upper):
    'function checks is the value is outside/within the range'
    if (lower >= x) or (x >= upper):
        return True
    else:     
        return False
for col in cols:
    quartile_01, quartile_03 = np.percentile(df[col].dropna(), [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_03 - quartile_01
    lower_bound = quartile_01 -(1.5 * iqr)
    upper_bound = quartile_03 +(1.5 * iqr)
    df['outlier'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: outlier_label(x, lower_bound, upper_bound))
    print(f"Out of range. For '{col}'. The lower and upper bound of the range for '{col}' respectively is: {lower_bound} and {upper_bound}")```
````